# Status bar notification for web app with PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developping a web app for iOS and Android, using the last version of PhoneGap.

I want to send Notifications to the users on their phone's status bar, and I cannot figure out how to do that.
It seems that there was a Cordova plugin (StatusBarNotification) that once existed, but all the links I find are dead.

If anyone knows a way to send notif to the statusbar, I would be grateful.

Thanks

Quentin

EDIT : I should have been more specific : I am trying to understand how to use the status area on phones (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), and for that I have a simple html file with a button. I want a notification to appear on the status area when I click the button. (like when you receive a text message, you have a notification).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Notiiiiiiif" id="btNotif"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            btNotif = document.getElementById('btNotif');
            btNotif.addEventListener('click', function(){
                //There I want a notif to appear in the status bar
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am testing this app on my Nexus 4, with Android 4.4.2.

EDIT : I ended up using Google Cloud Messaging (gcm) for android devices and Apple Push Notification (apn) on my node server. This works pretty well with android devices, a bit harder for iphones

Comment: do you mean push notification?

Comment: First I am simply trying a local notification by clicking a button. I edited first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps its already to late for the answer, but I think this would make sence for your furhter work with notifications in PhoneGap. For using [StatusBarNotifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) in latest versions of PhoneGap (v3.x), you need to a proper [Plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification) that will work. This should be installed with [Cordova CLI](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins).

For the older versions of PhoneGap ([v2.9](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/) and below) you still can use DEPRECATED version of StatusBarNotifications from [GitHub](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED).

By the way, using of older version is less headache for not experienced developers :)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks I knew I had to use a proper plugin but I couldn't find one. I even tried to code one myself ! I ended up using Google gcm and Apple apn but I think your solution will be way easier