# status bar notification in web application

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, notifications

I have a responsive web application and want to show notifications in the status bar of the mobile when the app is running in the mobile browser.
After googling the best I can find is this : [status-bar-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398975/status-bar-notification-for-web-app-with-phonegap-cordova)

I am unable to understand how this would help to show the notification.
Similar to the question in the aforementioned link I want to show notification on click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Notiiiiiiif" id="btNotif"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            btNotif = document.getElementById('btNotif');
            btNotif.addEventListener('click', function(){
                //There I want a notification to appear in the mobile status bar
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Recently came accross:

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/ .....looks very promising in achieving the same

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of notifications:

– Local notification, which you can generate IN your app.

– Push notifications, which are provided by Apple, Google, … or some notification providers.

For both you need a plugin, have a look at the [cordova plugin site](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/).

If you use local notifications, then the plugin generates the message in the status bar, not your JS! But you give the plugin the message, an icon and a badge number.

All of the notification handling has to be inside your app. That means for example: You have to remove notifications, if the are no more used, the count of badge numbers, etc..